# How can I change the Firebase Rules so that it no longer remains in test mode?

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, google-cloud-platform

[the rules console][1]

I really need help because I am currently developing my app in test mode but I don't want the Firebase to expire... Thankyou.. I edited the rules as per researching from Internet but still got an email from Google that my Firebase will expire in 4 days...
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBmia.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean change the Firestore database rule?
If so, you can modify the rule to:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true
    }
  }
}
```

It's not recommended but at least can solve your current problem. For more information, you can check https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules?authuser=2

Comment: Oh thankyou so much I've updated the rules, hoping Google doesn't send an email again! Again thankss